# What is the omega-completion of $ACA_0$

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, reverse-math, second-order-logic

The omega rule is an infinitary rule of logic which says that from $\phi(0),\phi(1),\phi(2),...$ you can infer $\forall n\phi(n)$.  My question is, what is the theory $T$ obtained by adding the omega rule to the system $ACA_0$?  And what relation does $T$ bear to stronger subsystems of second-order arithmetic than $ACA_0$?

Clearly $T$ proves more truths in the language of first-order arithmetic than $Z_2$ (second-order arithmetic) or any of its subsystems, since it proves them all.  But if $Th$ denotes all the truths in the language of first-order arithmetic, does $Z_2+Th$ prove all the consequences of $T$? And if so is the same true of $ATR_0+Th$ and the like?

Comment: I think you mean $Z_2$ (= first-order PA + extensionality + full induction and comperehension schemes) and not $PA_2$ - second-order PA is a *second-order* theory in the language of *first-order* arithmetic. As such there is no good notion of proof for $PA_2$, and $PA_2$ is complete in a very strong way (it has exactly one model up to isomorphism).

Comment: What is the difference between $Z_2$ and $PA_2$?  I was just referring to the standard axiom system that's a subsystem of $ZF$.  Does $PA_2$ denote the non-recursive second-order theory which is categorical with respect to standard semantics?  And what do you mean "second-order PA is a second-order theory in the language of first-order arithmetic"?  Isn't it in the language of second-order arithmetic?

Comment: Re: your comment, see the first part of my answer (the answer proper starts at "Now let's look at your question").